# AppEngine achieving strong consistency

Tags: python, google-app-engine, eventual-consistency

I am trying to achieve strong consistency. Let's call my model `PVPPlayer`:

```
class PVPPlayer(ndb.Model):
    points = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Every key for the model is created like this:

```
pvp_player = PVPPlayer(key=ndb.Key(Profile, "test_id", PVPPlayer, "test_id"))
```

where `Profile` is parent model:

```
class Profile(ndb.Model):
    def build_key(cls, some_id):
        return ndb.Key(cls, some_id)
```

I have 2 REST api url:

```
1) update_points
2) get_points
```

In 1) I do :

```
# I use transaction because I have to update all the models in single batch 
@ndb.transactional(xg=True, retries=3)
def some_func(points):
    pvp_player = ndb.Key(Profile, "test_id", PVPPlayer, "test_id").get()
    pvp_player.points += points 
    pvp_player.put()
    # update other models here`
```

In 2) I do:

```
pvp_player = ndb.Key(Profile, "test_id", PVPPlayer, "test_id").get()
return pvp_player.points`
```

My flow looks like this:

```
1) update_points()
2) get_points()
3) update_points()
4) get_points()`
...
```

**Problem**:

Using `get()` guarantees strong consistency so what I don't understand is why sometimes as the result of `get_points()` I get stale data like points were not updated at all.

**Example**:

```
POST get_points -> 0
POST sleep 1-3 sec
POST update_points -> 15
POST sleep 1-3 sec
POST get_points -> 15
POST sleep 1-3 sec
POST update_points -> 20
POST sleep 1-3 sec
POST get_points -> 15 !!!`
```

Comment: Is your #2 function also decorated with `@ndb.transactional`? Also, I presume the `update_points` function name in #1 is really `update_points`, right?

Comment: >Is your #2 function also decorated with @ndb.transactional?
I tried to add @ndb.transactional for #2 but it doesn't matter - it still gives me stale data from time to time
>update_points function name in #1 is really update_points, right?
Absolutely

Comment: Sorry, I meant `some_func` is `update_points`? :)

Comment: You may call some_func "commit" function. It updates PVPPlayer points and does save some other models like PVPMatch (some_func can operate at max 3 entity groups) but i do update PVPPlayer model only once in this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a case you exceed the write limit per entity group, that is one update per second? I think this could break the strong consistency of the entity group as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Physical player is the only one who updates PVPPlayer model. The situation when someone does 2 update_points() requests simultaneously for the the same model cannot happen at all according to game logic

Comment: Actually what is even more strange is that sometimes there is 15-20 sec gap between two sequantial update_points() but data are still stale so it behaves exactly like eventual consistency but I cannot understand why

Answer (score 2):

First check your logs, one of the updates must be failing with error, because your logic is basically correct.

Also double-check all your updates are wrapped in transactions to avoid races. [Cloud Datastore: ways to avoid race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955748/cloud-datastore-ways-to-avoid-race-conditions)

---

This case is likely not about consistency issues, but stomping updates, checkout this links for some interesting cases:

http://engineering.khanacademy.org/posts/transaction-safety.htm
http://engineering.khanacademy.org/posts/user-write-lock.htm

Comment: I just understood that one of my requests updates my parent model (i.e. Profile) simultaneously with update_points(). That looks like problem

Comment: Do I have to assign different parent key to avoid this problem right?

Comment: Everything that shares the parent key including the parent is in the same entity group.

Comment: @PeterLeontev wrap all your updates in transactions to avoid race conditions