# Google App Engine ndb: Order of mixed sync and async operations

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

When using Google App Engine `ndb`, do I have to worry about mixing synchronous and asynchronous put operations in the same function?

e.g. Say that I have some code like this:

```
class Entity(ndb.Model):
  some_flag = ndb.BooleanProperty()


def set_flag():
  ent=Entity()

  ent.some_flag = False
  ent.put_async()

  ent.some_flag = True
  ent.put()
```

Does that datastore take care of ensuring that all pending async writes are applied before the synchronous write (so that after `set_flag` runs, it is guaranteed that the flag will be `True`)? Or is there a race condition because the async put might complete after the synchronous put?

Answer (score 2):

No, the datastore does not take care of this for you.

Even with synchronous puts, calls from different threads can overwrite each other.

I recommend that you read up a bit on transactions, and when and why there are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For sample code, and a practical solution, you may have a look at Dan McGrath's reply to the "Cloud Datastore: ways to avoid race conditions" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955748/cloud-datastore-ways-to-avoid-race-conditions).